# How to convert expression to String, but keep it looking similar to input form?

Tags: string-manipulation

I have lots of differential equations, that I save to file (along with output and other things), as "strings", to process later in Latex and make a document of them.

I save each input differential equation, by first converting it from expression to String, then write it to the file (using `WriteString` command).

The problem is that when converting say `eq = y'[x] == 1/y[x]` to String, using `ToString` it becomes

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which ofcource does not work, when saved to file, since it messes up the lines in the text file. So I use `InputForm` like this `ToString[eq,InputForm]` and now it works, the string is flat and on one line:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is a string, and I can use that with no problem.

What I like however is to have the string look like the original expression, since it is easier to read (these will later show as verbatim in Latex), i.e. I need to convert expression to

```
   y'[x] == 1/y[x]
```

to same as above, but as string

```
   "y'[x] == 1/y[x]"
```

I do not use 2D math at all in my input. All my original Mathematica expressions are flat, read from plain text file, read them, and process them, then need to save them back as strings with other things for post-processing.

But I'd like to keep the same looking expression used, but as string.

Question: How to to convert  `y'[x] == 1/y[x]`  to string `"y'[x] == 1/y[x]"` ?

For example of one Latex output, here is a [link](http://12000.org/my_notes/Murphy_ODE/KEsu1.htm#subsection_1) to help explain what I mean.

Mathematica 11.0.1.

**Update:**

To answer comments, I have the ODE's in a list. Then I use a loop to process them. Here is a MWE, a very simplified  version. The process is completely non-interactive.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
lst = {{y'[x] == a*f[x]}, {y'[x] == x + Sin[x] + y[x]}, {y'[x] == 
     x^2 + 3*Cosh[x] + 2*y[x]}};
fileName = "result.txt";
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
Do[
  s = ToString[First@lst[[n]], InputForm];
  WriteString[file, s];
  WriteString[file, "\n"]
  , {n, 1, Length@lst}
  ];
Close[file]
```

The text file where these are saved to now looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In what form do you have the equations? In a list in an input cell? E.g.: `Cases[#, BoxData[b_] :> 
    StringJoin @@ Flatten[b /. RowBox -> List], -1] &@
 Cell[BoxData[
   RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{"y", "'"}], "[", "x", "]"}], "\[Equal]", 
     RowBox[{"1", "/", RowBox[{"y", "[", "x", "]"}]}]}]], "Input"]`

Comment: returns `{"y'[x]==1/y[x]"}` . You could extend this to a button a script to get all input cells in a certain notebook and you are done.

Comment: If you have `(*In[100]=*) y'[x] == 1/y[x]`, then `ToString[DisplayForm[ToExpression[InString[100]]]]` returns : `"y '[x] == 1/y[x]"` (with a blank between y and ') .

Comment: @RolfMertig thanks. I added an MWE. These are in a list. I do not know what each ODE looks like, there are 1,000's of them in  the list. So I can't hardcode things. I just showed one example.

Comment: @andre thanks. Can I use your method if the equations are in a list? as in the MWE I showed?

Comment: @Nasser I don't have solution for your MWE, even with the help of the interesting variable `$Line`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My approach for this sort of thing is to define conditioned `Format` rules for the problematic symbols, and then to `Block` the condition true when using `ToString`. In addition, I like to use `SequenceForm` as a substitute for `HoldForm`. In your example, I would do:

```
Format[Derivative[n_?Positive][f_], InputForm] /; $Nasser :=
SequenceForm[f, OutputForm@StringJoin[ConstantArray["'", n]]]
```

Then, I would define a special tostring function:

```
SetAttributes[tostring, HoldFirst]
tostring[expr_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{$Nasser = True, SequenceForm},
    SetAttributes[SequenceForm, HoldFirst];
    ToString[SequenceForm[expr], InputForm]
]
```

A couple examples:

```
tostring[y'[x] == a/y[x]] // InputForm
(* "y'[x] == a/y[x]" *)

tostring[x''[t] + c0 x'[t]^2 + c1 x[t]] // InputForm
(* "x''[t] + c0*x'[t]^2 + c1*x[t]" *)
```

Comment: How does `SequenceForm` work in this case? There isn't a lot of detail in the wolfram documentation. When I tried replacing SequenceForm with Row, Text, or Print -- things I assume are alternatives -- it no longer worked.

Comment: @1110101001 `SequenceForm` is a very special function that disappears when displayed using `InputForm`. You can think of it as the `InputForm` analog of `HoldForm`, except that `SequenceForm` doesn't hold any arguments. This is why `SequenceForm` is so useful when creating custom formats in `InputForm`.

Answer (score 2):

This is pure string hackery and I don't know how robust it is, but it works on your test case and one other that I tried.

```
helper[l_, d_] := l <> StringJoin @@ ConstantArray["'", ToExpression[d]]

SetAttributes[toPrimedForm, HoldFirst]
toPrimedForm[expr_] :=
  Module[{str},
    str[1] = ToString[HoldForm[expr], FormatType -> InputForm];
    str[2] = StringReplace[str[1], {"HoldForm[" -> "", "]" ~~ EndOfString -> ""}];
    StringReplace[
      str[2], 
      "Derivative[" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ "][" ~~ l : LetterCharacter ~~ "]" :> 
        helper[l, d]]]

toPrimedForm[y'[x] == 1/y[x]]
```

> `"y'[x] == 1/y[x]"`

```
toPrimedForm[x''[t] + c0 x'[t]^2 + c1 x[t]]
```

> `"x''[t] + c0*x'[t]^2 + c1*x[t]"`

Certainly it needs more testing and probably more work, but I'm short on time at the moment. Perhaps it will give you something you can develop further.

#### Update

Here is version written to work when passed an argument that is an ODE expression or a variables holding such an expression.

```
helper[l_, d_] := l <> StringJoin @@ ConstantArray["'", ToExpression[d]]

SetAttributes[toPrimedForm, HoldFirst]
toPrimedForm[expr_Symbol] := 
  Module[{str}, 
    str[1] = ToString[HoldForm[Evaluate@expr], FormatType -> InputForm];
    str[2] = StringReplace[str[1], {"HoldForm[" -> "", "]" ~~ EndOfString -> ""}];
    StringReplace[
      str[2], 
      "Derivative[" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ "][" ~~ l : LetterCharacter ~~ "]" :> 
        helper[l, d]]]
toPrimedForm[expr_] := Module[{xpr = expr}, toPrimedForm[xpr]]

expr = y'[x] == a/f[x];
toPrimedForm[expr]
```

> `"y'[x] == a/f[x]"`

```
toPrimedForm[y'[x] == a/f[x]]
```

> `"y'[x] == a/f[x]"`

Comment: @Nasser. I know it won't work if you have derivatives of order 10 or more or if you use multi-character dependent variable names.

Comment: it works on one example, when I removed the `SetAttributes[toPrimedForm,HoldFirst]`. But need to test it more. This is good so far....

Comment: @Nasser. I use the `HoldFirst` to preserve forms like `1/y`. If you evaluate expression like `expr = y'[x] == a/f[x]`, the front-end is going to mess up that expression before my function gets it. Could you live with `expr = HoldForm[y'[x] == a/f[x]]`? Then the `HoldFirst` could be dropped.

Comment: Will it show like `HoldForm[y'[x] == a/f[x]]` in the file you mean? Then no, since this can't be copied pasted from the web page. I'd like it to be just `"y'[x] == a/f[x]"` but I am trying your code now, without the `Hold` on it, else it does not work, since I need to pass expressions in variable. Not literally, since these are in a long list. As I have in MWE. Testing more now... thanks

Comment: @Nasser. No, it would strip the `HoldForm` off. It already does this now after it converts the expression to a string. The only change needed would be for it not to add `HoldForm` in its 1st step.