# Is there a style sheet that can be used to generate Stack Exchange input?

Tags: stylesheet

It would be convenient if there were a style sheet that automatically indented input cells, and automatically commented output cells, so that one could generate a stack exchange response in WL, and just copy the output. Is there such a style sheet?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-mathematica-notebook-to-stack-exchange-format#comment4302_990) is the description of a project with a similar goal. A download link is available in comments further down (but it will stop working when Dropbox disables public links in a couple of months.)

Comment: Look for the SENotebook package in the comments here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/has-someone-created-markdown-notebook-converter

Comment: @MichaelE2 and C.E: Oh wow. I myself forgot about my package :D Also, it's the 4 year anniversary of that one — "0.9 beta released 31 Dec 2012". In any case, Carl (and others): That notebook is a Mathematica -> SE prototype whereas yours is the other way round, but the stylesheet should probably still be useful. It's available publicly on Dropbox and Bitbucket, but I'll tidy that up and host it on Github, in case anyone wants to contribute and make it better :)

Comment: Since R. M.'s package got mentioned, I'll also link to [Kuba's implementation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84556); somebody might get inspired and come up with a total solution that eases back-and-forth between SE and *Mathematica*...

Comment: @J.M. following up on that I think I could build out a system that uses a `ServiceObject` to upload to SE on top of what I've alread built and go the other way too, even without much trouble. But I think such things  largely exist. Halirutan has his SEUploader which, unless I'm wrong, pushes a notebook to SE as an answer. And Carl has a largely functional downloader. If Halirutan included Carl's downloader in his uploader palette I think that would cover all the cases except chat.

Answer (score 29):

I've come up with a stylesheet to do this, given below. Some of the issues that I needed to address were:

1. Prevent cell labels from showing up.
2. Indent both input and output cells so that they are code.
3. Automatically comment the output.
4. Produce output that works correctly with Copy. That is, no need to use Copy As | Plain Text.
5. Allow one to copy multiple Code/Output/Text cells at once.
6. Support InputForm and FullForm.

Since the input typically uses white space to control appearance, I modified the Code style instead of the Input style.

1. To prevent cell labels from showing up, I needed to set `ShowCellLabel->False` at the notebook level. However, I still want to see the labels in a notebook. I did this by setting `ShowCellLabel->True` for Code, Input and Output cell styes.
2. To indent the input cells, I added a `CellEpilog` to the Code style, that looks for tabs, and inserts tabs if none are found. One could modify my code to look for spaces instead. To indent the output cells, I added a `CellEvaluationFunction` to the Code style. The `CellEvaluationFunction` also turned the output into a comment.  In both cases (`CellEpilog` and `CellEvaluationFunction`), one needs to use FullForm in some cases, e.g., `Pattern[a, Blank[]]` instead of `a_`:
3. Using `RawBoxes @ ToString[.., InputForm]` produces an Output cell that yields "Copy As | Plain Text" output when using the Copy command. This means one can highlight multiple cells, and then use the Copy (Ctrl-C) command, instead of using the right-click context menu to do Copy As.
4. Using `InputForm` or `FullForm` wrappers gave me some problems with `PageWidth`, so using the wrappers with long lines will need some post-processing help.
5. Use Alt-8 (Cmd-8 on a mac) to begin a Code cell. I gave Code cells a light blue background to indicate that they are cells intended to be copied to Stack Exchange.

Improvement suggestions are welcome.

The stylesheet is given below:

```
Notebook[
  {
  Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
  Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],ShowCellLabel->False,MenuSortingValue->10000],
  Cell[StyleData["Code"],
    CellEpilog :> With[{cellObject=EvaluationCell[]},
      NotebookWrite[cellObject,
        With[{cell=NotebookRead[cellObject]},
          Replace[cell,
            {
            Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"\t",BlankSequence[]}]],BlankSequence[]]->cell,
            Cell[BoxData[Pattern[a,Blank[]]],Pattern[b,BlankSequence[]]]:>Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"\t",ReplaceAll[a,"\n"->Sequence["\n","\t"]]}]],b]
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    CellEvaluationFunction ->
      (
      Replace[ToExpression[#1],
        {
        Alternatives[Null,$Failed]->Null,
        Alternatives[Pattern[e,Blank[InputForm]],Pattern[e,Blank[FullForm]]]:>RawBoxes[StringJoin["\t(* ",ToString[e]," *)"]],
        Pattern[e,Blank[]]:>RawBoxes[StringReplace[StringJoin["\t(* ",ToString[e,InputForm,PageWidth->60]," *)"],"\\\n"->"\\\n\t"]]
        }
      ]&
      ),
    InitializationCell->False,
    ShowCellLabel->True,
    MenuSortingValue->10000,
    Background->RGBColor[0.477119,0.957519,1]
  ],
  Cell[StyleData["Input"],ShowCellLabel->True,MenuSortingValue->10000],
  Cell[StyleData["Output"],ShowCellLabel->True,MenuSortingValue->10000]
  },
  Saveable->False,WindowSize->{808,689},WindowMargins->{{Automatic,143},{40,Automatic}},
  ShowCellLabel->False,
  FrontEndVersion->"11.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (July 28, 2016)",
  StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
]
```

Here's another version that uses Blockquote to display output:

```
Notebook[
  {
  Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
  Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],ShowCellLabel->False,MenuSortingValue->10000],
  Cell[StyleData["Code"],
    CellEpilog:>With[{cellObject=EvaluationCell[]},
      NotebookWrite[cellObject,
        With[{cell=NotebookRead[cellObject]},
          Replace[cell,
            {
            Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"\t",BlankSequence[]}]],BlankSequence[]]->cell,
            Cell[BoxData[Pattern[a,Blank[]]],Pattern[b,BlankSequence[]]]:>Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"\t",ReplaceAll[a,Rule["\n",Sequence["\n","\t"]]]}]],b]
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    CellEvaluationFunction->
      (
      Replace[ToExpression[#1],
        {
        Alternatives[Null,$Failed]->Null,
        Alternatives[Pattern[e,Blank[InputForm]],Pattern[e,Blank[FullForm]]]:>RawBoxes[StringJoin[">",ToString[e]]],
        Pattern[e,Blank[]]:>RawBoxes[StringJoin[">",ToString[e,InputForm]]]
        }
      ]&
      ),
    InitializationCell->False,
    ShowCellLabel->True,
    MenuSortingValue->10000,
    Background->RGBColor[0.477119,0.957519,1]
  ],
  Cell[StyleData["Input"],ShowCellLabel->True,MenuSortingValue->10000],
  Cell[StyleData["Output"],ShowCellLabel->True,MenuSortingValue->10000]
  },
  Saveable->False,WindowSize->{808,689},WindowMargins->{{Automatic,143},{40,Automatic}},
  ShowCellLabel->False,
  FrontEndVersion->"11.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (July 28, 2016)",
  StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
]
```

Comment: I love the idea of this but it doesn't seem to work on my system. (*Mathematica* 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64.)  When I evaluate one of the Code cells it runs seemingly forever without producing output.

Comment: I should have tested more thoroughly. Please try again, it works for me in M10 now.

Comment: Very cool!  Let me join others in saying it is a pleasure to have you on this site.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, as I alluded to in my OP, the syntax used inside of a style sheet can require FullForm input (e.g. Pattern[a, Blank[]]) instead of InputForm input (e.g. a_). This is what caused the kernel to hang for you. A few InputForm versions had snuck into my code in the process of copy/paste.

Comment: Umm...@Mr.Wizard...Who are these "others"? You seem to be the only person to have welcomed Carl to the site. (Sorry Carl, I guess I need to add a New Year's resolution to not pick on you... Neat idea, by the way)

Comment: @Daniel The Greek Chorus I carry in my head? :o)  [Leonid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134304/how-to-convert-expression-to-string-but-keep-it-looking-similar-to-input-form/134333#comment362448_134333) at least; I guess I just *assumed* there would be others.

Comment: I entered an expression such as `Sqrt[\[Alpha]]`, then copied it and pasted it into Stackexchange .. which repeated it as  `Sqrt[\[Alpha]]` ... It would be cool if the stylesheet could automate the conversion of same to something like Sqrt[ $\alpha$]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I always thought Leonid and Carl were sworn enemies from the DC Comics universe.

Answer (score 6):

My initial versions mangled the downvalues of Out, used by %. Also, my initial versions defaulted to InputForm.

*Edited to add support for compound/multiple expressions in an input, and to mark up messages.*

*Edited to fix bug when code cell is last cell of notebook*

*Edited to quiet messages during reformatting of cells*

> I've made some core changes to the style sheet.
>
> Previously, I used calls like `Cells[CellLabel->"Out[55]//FullForm="]` to find all of the output cells associated with an input. This required that I determined the line numbers of a cell when it contained multiple lines. I also used `NextCell[EvaluatedCell[]]` in the `CellProlog` to find the next cell before evaluation so that I could figure out what messages occurred for a given input.
>
> Now I use a more robust method. In the `CellProlog`, I give the evaluation cell the option `CellTags->"StackExchange"` and `CellLabelAutoDelete->False`. This combination means that all the cells generated from the input have the option `CellTags->"StackExchange"` and include the original `CellLabel`. Hence, it is much easier to find the associated cells using the `CellTags` option, and it is easy to restore the original `CellLabel` because the label hasn't been deleted. I also made a number of improvements to the formatting of output cells, to support forms like `TeXForm`, and to produce the normal plain text for output instead of `OutputForm`.
>
> Finally, I mentioned earlier that style sheets needed to use `FullForm` in some places. However, if you paste the `Notebook[]; NotebookPut@@%;` expression I give for the style sheet, it turns out that the conversion from `StandardForm` to `FullForm` needed for style sheets happens automatically. This means that I can rewrite my notebook expression so that it is a little bit easier to read, and I can include some comments.

An example of the use of the style sheets. Before evaluation, we have:

[image: Before evaluation]

After evaluation (using the *blockquote* style sheet), we have:

[image]

And, the version pasted using "Copy" (where all 3 cells are selected) is seen below:

```
    Row[{N[Pi,100], x^2, "c"}] //InputForm
```

> Row[{3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844376249654`100., x^2, "c"}]

```
Row[{N[Pi,100], x^2, "c"}] //FullForm
```

> Row[List[3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844376249654`100.,Power[x,2],"c"]]

```
Row[{N[Pi,100], x^2, "c"}]
```

> 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068x^2c

*Using the new multi-input/message markdown support*

Now, the following will work (here I use the *code* style sheet):

[image: multiple inputs]

which looks like the following when pasted:

```
1/0
Row[{N[Pi,100],b^2,"c"}]//FullForm
Sin[x,y];
3+6
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

```
(* ComplexInfinity *)

(* Row[List[3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375\
1058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679\
82148086513282306647093844376249654`100., 
Power[b, 2], "c"]] *)
```

> Sin::argx: Sin called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

```
(* 9 *)
```

The style sheets are given below, first the *code* style sheet, followed by the *blockquote* style sheet. Install by copying and evaluating the code below, then selecting Install Stylesheet:

**code style sheet**

```
Notebook[
    {
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    (* the Notebook style needs to have ShowCellLabel\[Rule]False so that copying the cells doesn't copy the label *)
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], ShowCellLabel->False, MenuSortingValue->10000],
    Cell[StyleData["Code"],
        (* CellTags and CellLabelAutoDelete options mean the generated cells include information needed for
         * postprocessing. The $Output PageWidth change is useful for creating strings with linebreaks *)
   CellProlog:>(
    SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellTags->"StackExchange", CellLabelAutoDelete->False];
    width=Options[$Output, PageWidth];
            SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth->60]
   ),
   CellEpilog:>Quiet @ With[{
    cellObject = EvaluationCell[],
    out = Cells[CellTags->"StackExchange", CellStyle->"Output"],
    message = Cells[CellTags->"StackExchange", CellStyle->"Message"]
    },
    SetOptions[$Output, width];

            (* reformat input/code cell if needed, and remove CellTags/CellLabelAutoDelete added in CellProlog *)
            Replace[NotebookRead[cellObject],
                Cell[BoxData[a_], "Code", b__Rule] :> 
                NotebookWrite[cellObject,
                    Cell[BoxData @ If[MatchQ[a, RowBox[{"\t", __}]],
                            a,
                            RowBox[{"\t", If[ListQ[a], RowBox, Identity] @ ReplaceAll[a,  "\n"->Sequence["\n","\t"]]}]
                        ],
                        "Code", TextClipboardType -> "PlainText", FilterRules[{b}, CellLabel]
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            (* add CellLabelAutoDelete\[Rule]False to the output cells so that the original CellLabel can be reused *)
            Map[SetOptions[#, CellLabelAutoDelete->False]&, out];

            (* add > to the beginning of Message cells *)
            Cases[message,
                obj_ :> Replace[NotebookRead[obj], 
                    Cell[BoxData[a_], s__String, b__] :>
                    NotebookWrite[obj, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{">", a}]], s, DeleteCases[{b}, CellTags->_]]]
                ]
            ];

            (* reformat output cells so that they appear as commented code *)
            Cases[out,
                obj_ :> Replace[NotebookRead[obj],
                    {
                    (* setting PageWidth\[Rule]60 in the Prolog means indenting adding indents is all that's needed *)
                    Cell[a_String, s__String, b__] :>
                    NotebookWrite[obj,
                        Cell[
                            StringJoin["\t(* ", StringReplace[a, "\n"->"\n\t"], " *)"],
                            s, TextClipboardType -> "PlainText", DeleteCases[{b}, CellTags|CellLabelAutoDelete->_]
                        ]
                    ],

                    (* ExportPacket produces a plaintext string, and ExportString adds linebreaks
                     * Some postprocessing of the ExportString output is needed
                     *)
                    c:Cell[_BoxData, s__String, b__] :>
                    NotebookWrite[obj,
                        Cell[
                            StringReplace[
                                ExportString[First@FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[c, "PlainText"], "Package", PageWidth->60],
                                Shortest[__]~~"\n\""~~o___~~"\"\n"~~EndOfString :>
                                "\t(* "<>StringReplace[o, {"\\\\"->"\\", "\\\n"->"\\\n\t", "\\"~~x_ :> x}] <>" *)"
                            ],
                            s, TextClipboardType -> "PlainText", DeleteCases[{b}, CellTags|CellLabelAutoDelete->_]
                        ]
                    ]
                    }
                ],
                {1}
            ]
        ],
        InitializationCell->False,
        ShowCellLabel->True,Background->RGBColor[0.477119`,0.957519`,1]
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"],ShowCellLabel->True],
    Cell[StyleData["Output"],ShowCellLabel->True]
    },
    Saveable->False,WindowSize->{808,689},WindowMargins->{{Automatic,143},{40,Automatic}},
    FrontEndVersion->"10.3 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (December 10, 2015)",
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
];
NotebookPut @ %;
```

**block quote style sheet**

```
Notebook[
    {
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    (* the Notebook style needs to have ShowCellLabel\[Rule]False so that copying the cells doesn't copy the label *)
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], ShowCellLabel->False, MenuSortingValue->10000],
    Cell[StyleData["Code"],
        (* CellTags and CellLabelAutoDelete options mean the generated cells include information needed for
         * postprocessing. The $Output PageWidth change is useful for creating strings with linebreaks *)
   CellProlog:>(
    SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellTags->"StackExchange", CellLabelAutoDelete->False];
    width=Options[$Output, PageWidth];
            SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth->60]
   ),
   CellEpilog:>Quiet @ With[{
    cellObject = EvaluationCell[],
    out = Cells[CellTags->"StackExchange", CellStyle->"Output"],
    message = Cells[CellTags->"StackExchange", CellStyle->"Message"]
    },
    SetOptions[$Output, width];

            (* reformat input/code cell if needed, and remove CellTags/CellLabelAutoDelete added in CellProlog *)
            Replace[NotebookRead[cellObject],
                Cell[BoxData[a_], "Code", b__Rule] :> 
                NotebookWrite[cellObject,
                    Cell[BoxData @ If[MatchQ[a, RowBox[{"\t", __}]],
                            a,
                            RowBox[{"\t", If[ListQ[a], RowBox, Identity] @ ReplaceAll[a,  "\n"->Sequence["\n","\t"]]}]
                        ],
                        "Code", TextClipboardType -> "PlainText", FilterRules[{b}, CellLabel]
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            (* add CellLabelAutoDelete\[Rule]False to the output cells so that the original CellLabel can be reused *)
            Map[SetOptions[#, CellLabelAutoDelete->False]&, out];

            (* add >- to the beginning of Message cells *)
            Cases[message,
                obj_ :> Replace[NotebookRead[obj], 
                    Cell[BoxData[a_], s__String, b__] :>
                    NotebookWrite[obj, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{">-", a}]], s, DeleteCases[{b}, CellTags->_]]]
                ]
            ];

            (* add > to output cells to produce blockquote formatting *)
            Replace[out,
                obj_ :> Replace[NotebookRead[obj],
                    {
                    Cell[a_String, s__String, b__] :>
                    NotebookWrite[obj,
                        Cell[StringJoin[">", a],
                            "Output", TextClipboardType -> "PlainText", DeleteCases[{b}, CellTags|CellLabelAutoDelete -> _]
                        ]
                    ],
                    Cell[BoxData[a_], s__String, b__] :> 
                    NotebookWrite[obj,
                        Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{">",a}]], 
                            "Output", TextClipboardType -> "PlainText", DeleteCases[{b}, CellTags|CellLabelAutoDelete -> _]
                        ]
                    ]
                    }
                ],
                {1}
            ]
        ],
        InitializationCell->False,
        ShowCellLabel->True,Background->RGBColor[0.477119`,0.957519`,1]
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"],ShowCellLabel->True],
    Cell[StyleData["Output"],ShowCellLabel->True]
    },
    Saveable->False,WindowSize->{808,689},WindowMargins->{{Automatic,143},{40,Automatic}},
    FrontEndVersion->"10.3 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (December 10, 2015)",
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
];
NotebookPut @ %;
```

Comment: My last edit was motivated by the case where a user sets On["Packing"]. In that case, we get messages due to unpacking while reformatting the cells for import into stack exchange. There shouldn't be any messages while reformatting the cells, unless there is a bug in the reformatting code, so the Quiet prevents any such message from being generated. If there is a bug in the reformatting code, one can remove the Quiet for debugging purposes.