# Copied Dot expression is incorrect

Tags: customization, output, code-request, copy-as

On a recent answer I ran into a little problem.  I wrote $x^3.\{1,1\}$ using *Mathematica*'s [2D input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html), then copied and pasted the expression here, yielding `x^3.{1, 1}`. This however is *not* equivalent:

```
x^3.{1, 1} // FullForm // HoldForm
```

> ```
> Times[Power[x, 3.`], List[1, 1]]
> ```

Either `x^3 .{1, 1}` or `(x^3).{1, 1}` would have been acceptable.

I should have spotted the problem myself but then again I feel I *should not have to*.

Can we make *Mathematica* copy expressions like this correctly?  I am encouraged that we can:

- [Is there a style sheet that can be used to generate Stack Exchange input?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134518/121)

Comment: `FrontEndExecute@
 ExportPacket[
  BoxData@RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["x", "3"], ".", 
     RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], "}"}]}],
  "InputText"
  ]` one can say it is a bug.

Comment: Route through expression works fine: `ToString[
 MakeExpression[
  RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["x", "3"], ".", 
    RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], "}"}]}],
  StandardForm
  ],
 InputForm
 ]`

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5676993